# Test a method by changing final static variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I have a protected Method which looks as follows.It uses final static variables from a Constants.java file.

```
class A {
    protected Configuration connectConfig() {
        ConfigDescriptor desc = new ConfigDescriptor.Builder()
            .project(Constants.REMOTE_CONFIG_PROJECT_NAME)
            .name(Constants.REMOTE_CONFIG_PROJECT_CONFIG_NAME)
            .version(Constants.REMOTE_CONFIG_PROJECT_VERSION)
            .build();

        return ConfigProvider.of(desc, getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

    public boolean process() {
        Configuration config = connectConfig();
        if(config == null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to unit test this method `process` for the `remote config` to fail.

If I just test `process()` method it will pass since the `Constants.java` has proper values to connect. For testing I want to change these values so that remote config `returns` `null`;

Note : We don't want to use `Mockito` to mock the values.

Comment: I'm confused... why can't you just temporarily change the values in constants.java?

Comment: @Austin : he tests run as part of a CI job so I dont want to change the actual values. Also we don't want to use Mockito to mock the values.

Comment: Can you not change any of the code then?

Comment: @Austin Unfortunately No :(

Answer (score 1):

Using a mocking framework such as [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html), you can define a spy of `A` in which you can specify the result of `connectConfig()`:

```
A spy = spy(new A());
doReturn(null).when(spy).connectConfig();

Assert.assertFalse(spy.process());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change constant values with [byteman](http://byteman.jboss.org). It should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mocking framework is almost always the wrong answer to this kind of question. Use dependency injection instead.